# How to make object bounce instead of just falling?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.10

So, i tried to make a soft body object and as a starting point, I made a dot that falls down.

```
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
import math
root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry("700x350")
c=tk.Canvas(root, width=700, height=350, background="white")
c.pack()
class point():
    def __init__(self,pos,vel):
        self.position=np.array(pos)
        self.velocity=np.array(vel)
    def show(self):
        x=self.position[0]
        y=self.position[1]
        c.delete("all")
        c.create_oval(x-4,y-4,x+4,y+4,fill='black')
class runner():
    def __init__(self,points,force):
        self.ps=points
        self.grav=force
    def update(self,dt):
        for p in self.ps:
            p.velocity=p.velocity+np.array(self.grav)*dt
            p.position=p.position+p.velocity*dt
            p.show()
ps=[point([350,350//2],[-2,-2])]
x=runner(ps,[0,0.1])
while True:
    x.update(1)
    root.update()
```

How should i make it bounce on the ground? I understand collision detection in python, but i am not sure about collision resolution.

**EDIT:** I am asking for a way to work out the direction and force the ball should go in after hitting floor.

The closest I have come is with:

```
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
import math
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("error")
root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry("700x350")
c=tk.Canvas(root, width=700, height=350, background="white")
c.pack()
class Collision:
    def __init__(self, normal=[0.0, 0.0], depth=float('-inf')):
        self.normal = np.array(normal)
        self.depth = np.clip(depth,-1000,100)

def find_collision(position):
    return Collision([0.0, 1.0], -(300-position[1]))

class point():
    def __init__(self,pos,vel):
        self.position=np.array(pos)
        self.velocity=np.array(vel)
    def show(self):
        x=self.position[0]
        y=self.position[1]
        c.delete("all")
        c.create_oval(x-4,y-4,x+4,y+4,fill='black')
class runner():
    def __init__(self,points,force):
        self.ps=points
        self.grav=force
        self.friction=10
        self.elasticity=1
    def update(self,dt):
        for p in self.ps:
            p.velocity=p.velocity+np.array(self.grav)*dt
            c = find_collision(p.position)
            
            if c.depth>=0:
                try:
                    p.position += c.normal * c.depth
                    p.position=np.clip(p.position,-345,345)
                    vn = c.normal * np.dot(c.normal, p.velocity)
                    vt = p.velocity - vn
                    
                    vn = -self.elasticity * vn
                    
                    vt *= math.exp(-self.friction * dt)
                    
                    p.velocity = vn + vt
                    
                except RuntimeWarning:
                    print(c.normal,c.depth)
            p.position=p.position+p.velocity*dt
            p.show()
ps=[point([350,350//2],[0,0])]
x=runner(ps,[0,0.1])
while True:
    x.update(1)
    root.update()
```

Comment: what's your question? How the math works?

Comment: The math is that the ball has an initial velocity of [-2,-2] (so it goes towards the top left corner) and has an acceleration of [0,0.1](so it starts going downwards to simulate gravity)

Comment: My question is that is it possible to work out where the balls need to go if the bottom is regarded as the floor. Oh, and sorry for not including comments in my code

Comment: yes it's possible with an if-statement. if x: "code block that does what you intend"

Comment: I get that bit but is there a formula or something similar to work out the velocity of the ball after it hits the floor @Thingamabobs

Comment: That's your choice, not mine.

Comment: I edited the question slightly please have a look

Comment: this might help you https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/bouncing-ball-equation-height-time-angle-90o.403229/

Comment: Thanks for helping out. Also, I would have moved this to chat but i don't have enough reputation.

Comment: What does the ball do?